# Fix row each printed page

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I need to configure one or more rows as header or footer to be printed on each page. I don't know the numbers of pages to print, it's dynamic.

Can I set several rows (or one) to be printed on each page using PHPExcel library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-rowscolumns-to-repeat-at-topleft):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setRowsToRepeatAtTopByStartAndEnd(1, 5);
```

Or if you want to use Headers/Footers that aren't spreadsheet rows, but part of the page setup, then (again from the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-the-print-header-and-footer-of-a-worksheet)).... useful for page numbering

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getHeaderFooter()
    ->setOddFooter('&L&B' . $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->getTitle() . '&RPage &P of &N');
```